# Преобразовать шорткод contact-form-7 в html

Tags: php, wordpress

Нужно перенести форму обратной связи в бутсраповское модальное окно

```
    <dl>
    <dt>Ваше имя</dt>
    <dd>[text* your-name]</dd>
    <dt>Ваш телефон</dt>
    <dd>[text* your-phone]</dd>
    <dt>Тема обращения</dt>
    <dd>[textarea* your-subject]</dd>
    <dt>Введите текст с изображение в поле ниже.
    Это вынужденная мера для борьбы со спамом, спасибо.</dt>
    <dd>[captchac captcha-170 size:l]<br>[captchar captcha-170]</dd>
    <dt>Все поля обязательны к заполнению</dt>
    <dd><input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" type="submit"  value="Отправить"></dd>
    </dl>
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: Вы не знаете как создать и работать с модальным окном в `Bootstrap`?

Comment: Нет, я не знаю как получить это форму в виде нормального html

Answer (score 1):

Как оказалось, надо лишь взять код из админки и вывести его через функцию do_shortcode

```
<?=do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="195" title="Заказ звонка"]')?>
```